# why use android studio to generate signed apk always wrong , apk can debug running

Tags: android

the app can running in debug mode.
eclipse no problem yet.
but if i use build->generate signed apk in android studio,There are a lot of mistakes , such as show below..

> Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]
>    public AdvanceDialogNoBalance(String unpaidSumMoney, String balance, String month)
>
> Error:(4) Error: "app_name" is not translated in "ja" (Japanese), "zh" (Chinese) [MissingTranslation]
>   Error:(5) Error: "action_settings" is not translated in "ja" (Japanese), "zh" (Chinese) [MissingTranslation]
>   Error:(6) Error: "drawer_open" is not translated in "ja" (Japanese), "zh" (Chinese) [MissingTranslation]
>   Error:(7) Error: "drawer_close" is not translated in "ja" (Japanese), "zh" (Chinese) [MissingTranslation]
>   Error:(10) Error: "cancel" is not translated in "ja" (Japanese), "zh" (Chinese) [MissingTranslation]
>   Error:(11) Error: "try_again" is not translated in "ja" (Japanese), "zh" (Chinese) [MissingTranslation]

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: ye,i use lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use next line code to avoid detection in gradle

> lintOptions {
>          abortOnError false
>    }